# XAMPP with HTTPS in new 2020 version not working, used to work

Tags: php, ssl, xampp

Hi guys I'm a bit dead inside so sorry if I'm too vocal.

I have installed the XAMPP with Apache and MySQL all pretty straight forward.

Now I need to make it working with HTTPS, as current Chrome keeps redirecting to HTTPs. Even when the site is opened it GETs pictures only via SSL.

I have created openSSL via guide online and installed it, added it to trusted certificates under Windows certificates. Then I added the following code to the httpd-xampp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/ikeen"
     ServerName ikeen.localhost
     ServerAlias *.ikeen.localhost
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/ikeen"
     ServerName ikeen.localhost
     ServerAlias *.ikeen.localhost
     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile "crt/ikeen.localhost/server.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/ikeen.localhost/server.key"
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have put simple html page inside. If I open via Incognito mode the HTTP link it shows it, as soon as I try to access it via HTTPS I get (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).

Any possible ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Guys for everyone who is ever struggling there. This is Kaspersky Antivirus work that prevents local sites working.